# An array don't show the values

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

**Hello!**

I try to extract the values from an array (**prepTime**), but it don't show them. When I compile the program I get an error:

```
0xec80b0:  cmpl   (%eax), %ecx        Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xff31e10)
```

**Here I created the array:**

```
{
    NSArray *tableData;
    NSArray *thumbnails;
    NSArray *prepTime;    //Here I created the array
}
```

**Here I filled it with values:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", ... @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];

    // Initialize thumbnails
    thumbnails = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"egg_benedict.jpg", ... @"angry_birds_cake.jpg", @"ham_and_cheese_panini.jpg", nil];

    //Initialize prep time
    prepTime=[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"90 min", "60 min", "45 min", ... "10 min", "60 min", "40 min",   nil];
}
```

As you can see there are three arrays in my code were defined and filled with values, but only '**prepTime**' array don't show it values in my table cell and give an error when compile it instead.

***Why it happens?***

**Thanks a lot!**

Comment: You are not using the proper syntax.For any string to be stored use @"".You have missed that only for objects in prepTime array.

Comment: OMG! How I could have made this mistake!? 
I do the same arrays a lot of time and didn't do this mistake... :) I'm so embarrassed... :)
Thanks guy! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have missed a few `@` signs in some of your string literals:

```
prepTime=[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"90 min", "60 min", "45 min", ... "10 min", "60 min", "40 min",   nil];
//                                             ^Here     ^Here         ^Here     ^Here     ^Here
```

Trying to access the resultant C strings as `NSString` causes bad access.

Comment: ... it rather *tends to* cause a segfault, but it technically could be anything else (like nasal daemons) as this is UB. +1 btw.

Comment: OMG! How I could have made this mistake!? 
I do the same arrays a lot of time and didn't do this mistake... :) I'm so embarrassed... :)
Thanks guy! :)